# Class Method with a Function/Predicate Parameter

Tags: vb.net, methods, predicate

I have a class whose primary class member is a `Dictionary(Of DateTime,CustomClass)`.  I would like to write a method that deletes elements of the dictionary if certain conditions are met, similar to a `.Where(Function(p) p.isTrue)` function.  I have found documentation on USING a predicate, but nothing on building with one.  Is this possible?

Comment: I have this in a class to do mapping but it seems overwrought for the little bit you described.  Couldnt you pass the criteria data to the method.  Some params might be optional and skipped when they are the default

Answer (score 0):

I am usually all gung-ho for LINQ, but this is a situation where I think that you should iterate through the Dictionary backward using a For/Next loop and remove the items that don't meet your conditions:

```
Public Class Foo

    'Primary class member
    Public Property Bar As Dictionary(Of DateTime, Foo)

    'Remove method based on some condition (you may want to pass a parameter here too)
    Public Sub Remove()
        'Use a For/Next loop backwards
        For index As Integer = Me.Bar.Keys.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            'Check for if the condition is met and then remove the item by its index
            'If ... Then
            '    Me.Bar.Remove(Me.Bar.ElementAt(index).Key)
            'End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        Me.Bar = New Dictionary(Of DateTime, Foo)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more dynamic, also it was a slightly academic exercise as well.  The problem with this, is that it only works for 1 condition.  I was hoping to be able to use the same method for date comparisons or attributes of `Foo`.

Comment: It isn't solely for dates, you would simply set all of the conditions (date and your custom class) in the If statement. Give me a more specific example and I'll provide you with a better example.

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to pass the condition as a parameter so that he wouldn't have to hardcode it in the `Remove()` function. Something like what Bozhidar suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Just declare a method with a `Func(Of...`) argument, which represents the condition:

```
Public Sub RemoveElementIf(condition As Func(Of KeyValuePair(Of DateTime, Foo), Boolean))

    If condition IsNot Nothing Then Bar = Bar.Where(Function(x) condition(x))

End Sub
```

Then you can use LINQ internally.